# Delete everything except first line

Tags: bbedit

This should be simple, but I'm stumped.

I'm starting with:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line n
```

And I want to end up with:

```
Line 1
```

I'm using BBEdit, doing a search and replace with grep -- replacing with nothing.

Comment: I don't understand, are you working with a file? Are you on some Linux distro?

Comment: Regular expressions are for pattern matching. What specific pattern are you trying to match? If you don't have one, then grep is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: I'm automating some tasks. One step is to take the first line of a file and paste it somewhere else. The easiest way of doing this for me is to delete everything except the first line and then pass the results on.

Comment: The pattern would be from the first line break to the end of file.

Comment: grep is not the right tool for this job...you can just use `head -1`

Comment: If you insist to do it with grep you can make use of `-m1` command line switch = stop at first match ==> `grep -m1 '^.*$'`

Comment: Appreciate all the quick replies.
Not using command line, though. I'm using Text Factory in BBEdit on a Mac to automate this. No other choice in tools. I can automate search and replace with grep -- searching for a regular expression and replacing with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
\r([^<]*)
```